# VideoDisplay class does not show preview of frames when draging the track slider

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming

I'm using Flex 3 VideoDisplay class for playing streaming video. When I drag the track slider(change the playheadTime) there are no preview frames even if that part of the video is already loaded.

Is there anything I can do to enable this feature (from the configuration of media server or in the Flex client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but since no one provided meaningful answer...

There is [inBufferStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#inBufferSeek) property of [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) class which is default set to false. Set it to true, and you will be able to seek in the buffered content(since Flash 10.1).

Answer (score 1):

The track slider needs to be sending updates to the display as they occur.  My guess since there isn't any code is that you have something like a horizontal slider for changing the playhead (we call this a scrub bar).

Common thing you might be missing is `liveDragging="true"` on that `hslider` scrub bar.

If you can post code I can get more specific  :)